# How to convert Azure Backup report Duration column to Date time with decimal numbers

Tags: python, pandas, azure, datetime

The Duration column from Azure cloud backup report seems to have a funny time format (decimal after the hour and after the minute). Can you please help round the hour, minute and seconds part such that the column is in Hours?

```
1.05:27:39.9470724
21:17.7
21:41.4
1.02:42:37.1136811
21:17.2
```

I tried to format the microseconds part but not sure how to workaround these decimal in hour part. Happy to just exclude these decimals.

```
appended_data['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(appended_data['Duration'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
ValueError: time data '1.05:27:39.9470724' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f' (match)
```

```
appended_data['Backup Size'] = appended_data['Backup Size'].str.replace('MB','')
appended_data['DurationFixed'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'].str.split(':',expand=True)\
                    .stack()\
                    .astype(float)\
                    .round()\
                    .astype(int).astype(str).unstack(1).fillna('00').agg(':'.join,axis=1),
               unit='s')
appended_data['DurationHours'] = appended_data['DurationFixed'] / np.timedelta64(1,'h')



appended_data['Duration']
1    04:01:22.7756139
1    03:31:17.0678262
1    04:41:32.7253765
1    03:11:18.3396588
1    04:51:20.2017034
           ...       
1    02:21:17.8554095
1    02:21:19.5547075
1    03:41:23.8876812
1    02:21:32.5529160
1    02:01:20.3247238


appended_data['DurationFixed']
1   02:01:20
1   02:01:20
1   02:01:20
1   02:01:20
1   02:01:20
      ...   
1   02:01:20
1   02:01:20
1   02:01:20
1   02:01:20
1   02:01:20
```

Thanks

MM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a strange error as I've never seen any logs from azure like this - regardless, unless there is some inbuilt method to handle data like this we will need to parse it out manually.

We will split by `:` and then round the numbers before re-creating the time-delta string.

I have to be clear and say that this is *not* a true fix as you need to qualify what `1.05` is, is that 1hour and x minutes?

if you don't care about the above then the below should work.

## Method 1 No Precision, string formatting.

```
print(df)

             Duration
0  1.05:27:39.9470724
1             21:17.7
2             21:41.4
3  1.02:42:37.1136811
4             21:17.2
```

---

```
df['DurationFixed'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'].str.split(':',expand=True)\
                    .stack()\
                    .astype(float)\
                    .round()\
                    .astype(int).astype(str).unstack(1).fillna('00').agg(':'.join,axis=1),
               unit='s')
                

print(df)

           Duration DurationFixed
0  1.05:27:39.9470724      01:27:40
1             21:17.7      21:18:00
2             21:41.4      21:41:00
3  1.02:42:37.1136811      01:42:37
4             21:17.2      21:17:00
```

if you want only hours can you convert it using `np.timedelta64`

```
import numpy as np

df['DurationFixed'] / np.timedelta64(1,'h')
0     1.461111
1    21.300000
2    21.683333
3     1.710278
4    21.283333
Name: DurationFixed, dtype: float64
```

---

## Method 2 with more precision.

if your data is in the same format - i.e `Hours : Minutes : Seconds`

we could stack and apply a cumulative count and map metadata fields to use our `pd.to_timedelta` at a row level.

```
s = df['Duration'].str.split(':',expand=True)\
                    .stack()\
                    .astype(float).to_frame('time_delta')

print(s)

     time_delta
0 0   1.050000
  1  27.000000
  2  39.947072
1 0  21.000000
  1  17.700000
2 0  21.000000
  1  41.400000
3 0   1.020000
  1  42.000000
  2  37.113681
4 0  21.000000
  1  17.200000
```

---

```
s['metadata'] = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount().map({0 : 'h', 1 : 'm', 2 : 's' })

print(s)

    time_delta metadata
0 0   1.050000        h
  1  27.000000        m
  2  39.947072        s
1 0  21.000000        h
  1  17.700000        m
2 0  21.000000        h
  1  41.400000        m
3 0   1.020000        h
  1  42.000000        m
  2  37.113681        s
4 0  21.000000        h
  1  17.200000        m
```

Finally, we use an `apply` at a row level to cast each row to its repsective format and round to the nearest `n` seconds. I've chosen 10.

```
df['DurationPrecise'] = s.apply(lambda x : pd.to_timedelta(x.time_delta,
                                x.metadata,errors='coerce'),axis=1)\          
              .groupby(level=0).sum().dt.round('10s')


print(df)

             Duration DurationFixed DurationPrecise
0  1.05:27:39.9470724      01:27:40        01:30:40
1             21:17.7      21:18:00        21:17:40
2             21:41.4      21:41:00        21:41:20
3  1.02:42:37.1136811      01:42:37        01:43:50
4             21:17.2      21:17:00        21:17:10
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate - much appreciated. I had to reset_index(drop=True) before I could use your code. Thanks again

Comment: hey - I finally realise what the decimal point in the hh part means. It is actually Days and so we need to multiply that by 24 to get the total hours. Can you help please?

Comment: @MrunalModi I'd recommend a new question maybe add the documenation where u got information from too

Comment: OK - I got that from the customer when I noticed that the duration of xfer was 2.5 hours for data being 13TiB which in fact was 2 Days and 5 hours.

Comment: @MrunalModi I see, thats a maassive transfer. so would 1.05 = 1 * 0.5 = 1.5 days in total? or 0.5 days

Comment: 1.5 Days :) check my answer. Yours is a more pandas friendly version which would be nice as compared to my function.

Comment: @MrunalModi I recommend asking a new question i dont have time right now to answer but others will be able to answer for you

Comment: All good, I have a solution - posted my answer here on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Based on analyzing the data, I can conclude that the decimal place in the hh section is in fact days. Example 2.4:30:30 = 2 Days, 4 hours, 30 min, 30 sec.

```
def cleanhours(x):
    hms=x.split(":")
    dh=hms[0].split(".")
    if len(dh)>1:
        hms[0]=str(int(dh[-1])+24*int(dh[-2]))
    hms[2] = hms[2].split(".")[0]
    return int(hms[0])+int(hms[1])/60.0+int(hms[2])/3600.0
#     return ":".join(hms)
```